# Why is the Touchable area more than the image Using Touchable react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am doing a simple image and trying to get an alert when clicked on it, but the image is still clickable.
I tried hitslop, to reduce the clickable area but it still does nothing. Any help would be appreciated. This is the image I am using in the code.

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, TouchableOpacity, Image, ScrollView, Alert } from "react-native";
import * as ScreenOrientation from "expo-screen-orientation";
const ImageComponent = ({ source }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity hitSlop={{top: -80}} onPress={() => Alert.alert("Image clicked!")}>
    <Image
        source={require("./resources/Freezer_11.png")}
        style={styles.image}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
);
const App = () => {

  return (
      <ImageComponent/>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  image:{
    aspectRatio:1,
    resizeMode:"contain",
    margin:0,
    padding:0,
  }
});

export default App;
```

I am trying to use the image as button. So, I wrapped Touchable to the image but the touchable area is more than the image for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

let change image styles like this:

```
width: 200,
height: 200
```

your problem is the resizeMode, image not find the whole parent view, but it's still take space, which clickable from `Touchable` View